# How to join two querysets from different model to create a new queryset with additional fields?

Tags: python, mysql, django, join, django-queryset

Currently on Django/MySQL setup

I need to join two queries from different models into one but unlike CHAIN or UNION(), I need the final queryset's record set to expand to include data retrieved from both queries based on the common key (sales_date) as well as a SUM field.  Please see below for better explanation of my question:

querysetA:

| id | sales_date | store_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-15 | 2000.00 |
| 2 | 2020-01-16 | 1000.00 |
| 3 | 2020-01-17 | 3000.00 |

querysetB:

| id | sales_date | online_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-15 | 1500.00 |
| 2 | 2020-01-16 | 800.00 |
| 3 | 2020-01-17 | 2800.00 |

Joined querysetC from querysetA and B (my target result querysetC):

| id | sales_date | store_sales | online_sales | combine_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-15 | 2000.00 | 1500.00 | 3500.00 |
| 2 | 2020-01-16 | 1000.00 | 800.00 | 1800.00 |
| 3 | 2020-01-17 | 3000.00 | 2800.00 | 5800.00 |

My code for both querysets as below (both working and giving me the correct results):

```
    querysetA = store_shop.objects.filter(
        sales_date__range=(fromdate, todate)) \
        .values('sales_date') \
        .annotate(store_sales=Sum('sales_income')) \
        .order_by('sales_date')

    querysetB = online_shop.objects.filter(
        sales_date__range=(fromdate, todate)) \
        .values('sales_date') \
        .annotate(online_sales=Sum('sales_income')) \
        .order_by('sales_date')
```

Both union() and itertools.chain does not give me what I want.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason it has to be a queryset and not handled in Python?

Comment: Just that I am already working on passing the dict to generate charts from queryset, so was wondering if such can be done along the way, since my search for any relating result came up empty.  Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not possible to keep it as a queryset. But you could use list-comprehension to create a list of dictionaries that contain the correct data (and maybe references to the original objects.

Comment: Yes, think so too, thanks for the tip!